# Why does the designer need System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize in a Winform?

Tags: c#, winforms

I can build a winform with controls without ever using ISupportInitialize why do the designer need it ?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isupportinitialize.aspx).

FTA:

> ISupportInitialize allows controls to
>   optimize multiple property
>   assignments. As a result, you can
>   initialize co-dependent properties or
>   batch set multiple properties at
>   **design** time.